# How does hydraulic press work at molecular level?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, energy, fluid-statics

Let's consider the following arrangement:

[image]

I know that because of conservation of energy the force on the car has to be amplified. The work $W$ done is

$$W = \text{Force} \cdot \text{distance} \, ,$$

which in turn is the amount of energy transferred.

How is this force amplified at the molecular level. For example, if we put sand in place of water and suppose that the molecules are connected with springs then can we show that the springs will get compressed in such a way so as to amplify the force on the car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the figure: *liquid that cannot be compressed*... so forget compression of springs.

Molecularly, particles in a liquid have much less space to move around (short mean free paths) compared to particles in a gas. The result is that any applied pressure to these particles is [*instantaneously*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound) transferred [*through*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_law) the fluid. The mechanism by which this happens is the collision of particles which exchange kinetic energy/momentum. The amplification of the force occurs because the area at position 2 is much larger so many more particles can impose a force there compared to the piston at position 1.

Imagine you impose a pressure $p$ at position $1$, by conservation of mechanical energy (disregard effects of gravity), this must be the same pressure at position $2$. So we can state:
$$p=\frac{F_1}{A_1}=\frac{F_2}{A_2}\rightarrow\frac{F_2}{F_1}=\frac{A_2}{A_1}$$
If we assume $A_2/A_1\gg1$ like in the figure it follows, $F_2/F_1\gg1$, i.e. a small force at position $1$ translates to a large force at position $2$.

By conservation of energy the amount of work $W$ at position $1$ must be the same as at position $2$, i.e.:
$$W=F_1\Delta x_1=F_2\Delta x_2\rightarrow\frac{\Delta x_2}{\Delta x_1}=\frac{F_1}{F_2}\ll1$$
We find that displacement of the piston at position $2$ is only a fraction of the displacement of the pistion at position $1$.

Comment: But what happens at the molecular level? I am looking for this type of explanation: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22994/93864 I know that the energy is transferred in someway which amplifies the force. But what is that way?

Comment: That answer deals with solids which usually has particles in lattices structures; this could be modeled with springs. Fluids cannot (generally) be modeled this way because they have much more freedom than particles in solids. The mechanism you are looking for is the collision of particles which exchange kinetic energy/momentum. The amplification occurs because the area at position $2$ is much larger so many more particles can impose a force there compared to the piston at position $1$.

Comment: ...where "instantaneously" means "at the speed of sound in the fluid."

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for. The number of particles are more at 2. A lot of particles get K.E from 1 and reach at 2 and strike simultaneously. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Sorry but how do you say the pressure is (and compare displacements of the two) equal using conservation of energy? I though it was done by writing horizontal force equations on horizontal and vertical columns of water. How is energy conserved ?

Comment: @Skawang - there are many roads to Rome; you can use both approaches to show the pressure remains approximately constant under idealized conditions. Consider looking at [Bernoulli's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_principle) or the [Navier-Stokes equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations).

Comment: I am not that deep into fluid mechanics yet so I don't understand the Navier Stokes equations. So by conservation of energy, you mean the equation $v^2/2+gH+\frac{P}{\rho}=Constant$ ? It explains the constant pressure but doesn't explain how you said work at position 1 = work at postion 2

Comment: @Skawang - Yes exactly and the navier-stokes equations reduce to $\boldsymbol{\nabla}p=0$ which is the same result. The work can be seen by realizing that, since we are dealing with an incompressible fluid, any volumetric displacement $\Delta V=A\Delta x$ by the small piston must be equaled by the large piston. So $W_1=p_1dV_1=F_1\Delta x_1$ and $W_2=p_2dV_2=F_2\Delta x_2$, the pressures are the same, the volumetric displacement is the same, so the work must be the same. Actually just the volumetric displacement will give the same result: $\Delta V=A_1\Delta x_1=A_2\Delta x_2$ if rearranged.

Comment: In case of liquid and gas the reason of force amplification is the K.E. of particles which strike at 2 in greater amount. But if use some kind of solid gel material in which particles get bonded with each other, how would then force amplify at molecular level?

Comment: @user - How fluid is a 'solid gel' material? As long as it is fluid in that it fills the container it is in, the force will be amplified. I am unsure if a solid can be used to achieve the same result, my intuition say 'no' because the mechanism of K.E. transfer is different in solids than in liquids (no collisions and freedom to move).

Comment: By gel I meant something like the toothpaste material. And for solids too the energy has to be conserved. If we use small solid iron balls greased well so as to diminish friction then the same conservation of energy principle demands the force to be amplified at 2.

Comment: @user - agreed, but by using 'small solid iron balls' you are effectively describing a fluid which consist of small 'solid' particles :). I would expect the same result in that case as with a fluid. Toothpaste i expect works as well, however as toothpaste is a non-newtonian fluid, the above analysis may need to account for viscous dissipation.

Comment: How does the particles rearrange them at 2? For covering larger area the small particles have to go sideways, which will make there velocity vector slanted. There total K.E. will be divided in two parts one in forward direction the other one in perpendicular. The perpendicular part won't be able to contribute in amplification of force in forward direction.

Comment: @user - you are overthinking this; kinetic energy is a scalar quantity, it has no direction and can't be decomposed in different contributions. Fluid particles also are in constant random motion (speed of sound in air ~300 m/s) even if there is no bulk motion of the fluid. So their velocity vector at position $2$ is not in any preferred direction. The small 'solid' particles will have to be small enough to have the same freedom of movement as the fluid particles.